# How to Add JPanel to JScrollPane While JPanel Has Component Bigger Than Itself?

Tags: java, swing

My question shows I'm new in JAVA ;)

I'm trying to add a `JPanel` to `JScrollPane` but When I add a component bigger  than `JPanel` the `JScrollPane` does not work.

I can fix it by setting JScrollPane smaller than `JPanel` but this is not a right solution ( I want to add components to `JPannel` dynamically later).

scroll2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

What is solution? Thank you

public class Main extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel finalPan2;
JScrollPane scroll2;

public Main() throws HeadlessException {
    super("V4.0.3");
    try {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setSize(520, 540);
    setLocation(0, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

    finalPan2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    finalPan2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 540));

    JButton bb = new JButton("Big Button");
    bb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 800));
    finalPan2.add(bb);

    scroll2 = new JScrollPane(finalPan2);
    scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    add(scroll2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        // @Override
        public void run() {

            Main ba = new Main();

        }
    });

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: JScrollPane does not go up and down when big button added to Jpanel. you can see if scroll2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); line elimated.

Comment: Ah. I think it's because you have the ScrollPane for the Panel, but the Panel doesn't change size for the Button. What happens if you don't set the preferred size of the JPanel?

Comment: Yes, now it works :) Thank you. But adds components in a row not under each others! how can I fix this?

Comment: That has to do with the Panel's LayoutManager. You're using a `FlowLayout`, which I know nothing about. I'd suggest looking at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for help on deciding which manager to use and how to code for it.

Comment: Thank you, you solved the problem. If you put your comment as answer I can vote it for correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `ScrollPane` for the `JPanel`, but the `JPanel` doesn't change size to accomodate for the size of the `JButton` because you have set its preferred size. If you take out `finalPan2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 540));`, the panel should resize to fit the button, and the scrollpane should work.